# How to config Buildroot to get more free space without change EXT2_SIZE?

Tags: linux, sd-card

When build with Buildroot v2014.02, my image rootfs.ext2 is aout 200M.
After programming into SD card, we can get nearly max free space.

```
# df -h
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root                 7.2G    198.1M      6.6G   3% /
```

When build with Buildroot v2019.02, 
if set BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_SIZE="200M", image rootfs.ext2 is aout 200M.
After programming into SD card, we can only get 68M free space.

And if I set BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_SIZE="1024M", the image file rootfs.ext2 is about 1.1G.
After programming into SD card, we can get around (1024-200)M free space.

the image size gets bigger even though I only want to get more free space.

Is it possible to config v2019.02 file system size works the same as v2014.02, get all the free space if sd card has.

Any ideas appreciated.